Kickstart File Not Used During RHEL 6.9 Installation on UEFI System
Question:
I followed the Red Hat documentation to create a Kickstart (ks) file located in the root directory of the installation image. The documentation I referred to is: Red Hat Installation Guide. I am using the rhel-server-6.9-x86_64-dvd.iso image.
Problem:
After modifying and generating the image according to the steps, I mounted it via HTTP to an HP server. Upon rebooting the server into the installation steps, it did not use the ks file for installation. Instead, it entered the media test option. After manually selecting "skip", it went into the graphical installation interface, and the ks file did not seem to take effect.
My Server Configuration:

Server Model: HP
Boot Mode: UEFI ISO
Image: rhel-server-6.9-x86_64-dvd.iso

Steps I Have Tried:
Followed the steps in the Red Hat documentation: Installation Guide Modified and generated the image as per the guide. Mounted the image via HTTP to the server.
Actual Result:
Upon rebooting the server, it enters the media test option. After manually selecting "skip", it enters the graphical installation interface. The ks file is not used.
Expected Result:
The server should automatically use the ks file for installation upon reboot, instead of entering the media test option.
Relevant Code or Configuration Files:
isolinux/isolinux.cfg
# isolinux/isolinux.cfg
default vesamenu.c32
#prompt 1
timeout 600

display boot.msg

menu background splash.jpg
menu title Welcome to Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.9!
menu color border 0 #ffffffff #00000000
menu color sel 7 #ffffffff #ff000000
menu color title 0 #ffffffff #00000000
menu color tabmsg 0 #ffffffff #00000000
menu color unsel 0 #ffffffff #00000000
menu color hotsel 0 #ff000000 #ffffffff
menu color hotkey 7 #ffffffff #ff000000
menu color scrollbar 0 #ffffffff #00000000

label linux
  menu label ^Install or upgrade an existing system
  menu default
  kernel vmlinuz
  append initrd=initrd.img inst.ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg
label vesa
  menu label Install system with ^basic video driver
  kernel vmlinuz
  append initrd=initrd.img nomodeset
label rescue
  menu label ^Rescue installed system
  kernel vmlinuz
  append initrd=initrd.img rescue
label local
  menu label Boot from ^local drive
  localboot 0xffff
label memtest86
  menu label ^Memory test
  kernel memtest
  append -

ks.cfg
#ks.cfg
#platform=x86, AMD64, or Intel EM64T
#version=DEVEL

# Install OS instead of upgrade
install

# Use CDROM installation media
cdrom

# Use text mode install
text

# Keyboard layouts
keyboard --vckeymap=us --xlayouts='us'

# System language
lang en_US.UTF-8 --addsupport=zh_CN.UTF-8,zh_TW.UTF-8

# System authorization information
auth --useshadow --passalgo=sha512

# Root password
rootpw --iscrypted $1$1gxQXmsEo$VxO.PGlcdpalNRcxYbansxzxxv.9.

# System timezone
timezone Asia/Shanghai --isUtc --nontp

# SELinux configuration
selinux --disabled

# Network configuration
network --onboot yes --bootproto=static --device=9c:dc:71:b5:a4:b8 --ip=10.15.29.10 --netmask=255.25.25.0 --gateway=10.15.29.1 --noipv6
network --hostname=temptest

# Additional repository configuration
repo --name="Server-HighAvailability" --baseurl=file:///run/install/repo/addons/HighAvailability
repo --name="Server-ResilientStorage" --baseurl=file:///run/install/repo/addons/ResilientStorage

# Firewall configuration
firewall --disabled

# Firstboot configuration
firstboot --disable

# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr --boot-drive=sda

# Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel --drives=sda

# Disk partitioning information
part /boot/efi --fstype="efi" --ondisk=sda --size=2048 --fsoptions="umask=0077,shortname=winnt"
part /boot --fstype="xfs" --ondisk=sda --size=2048
part / --fstype="xfs" --ondisk=sda --size=102400
part /oracle --fstype="xfs" --ondisk=sda --size=102400
part /Data --fstype="xfs" --ondisk=sda --size=902921
part swap --fstype="swap" --ondisk=sda --size=16384
part swap --fstype="swap" --ondisk=sda --size=16384


# Package installation
%packages
@^graphical-server-environment
@base
@core
@desktop-debugging
@dial-up
@fonts
@gnome-desktop
@guest-agents
@guest-desktop-agents
@hardware-monitoring
@input-methods
@internet-browser
@multimedia
@print-client
@x11
%end

# Service configuration
services --disabled="chronyd"

# Kdump configuration
%addon com_redhat_kdump --disable --reserve-mb='auto'
%end

# Anaconda password policy
%anaconda
pwpolicy root --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --notempty
pwpolicy user --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --emptyok
pwpolicy luks --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --notempty
%end

# Reboot after installation
reboot

Command to generate a new image
mkisofs -U -r -v -T -J -joliet-long -V "RHEL-6" -volset "RHEL-6" -A "RHEL-6" -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -
eltorito-alt-boot -e images/efiboot.img -no-emul-boot -o /Data/http/os/rhel-6.9-new.iso .
implantisomd5 /Data/http/os/rhel-6.9-new.iso

Question:
Could the issue be related to the UEFI boot mode of my server? Do I need to add specific options to the boot parameters to ensure the ks file is used?

Yes, the UEFI mode is at the heart of your issue. The isolinux bootloader is used in legacy BIOS boot mode only: if your system boots in UEFI mode, the entire isolinux.cfg will be completely ignored.
Instead, you should add the inst.ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg option to the appropriate kernel line in EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.conf of the ISO image file, and/or in the second copy of the same file located in a FAT filesystem image file images/efiboot.img.
In other words, just before your mkisofs command, while already in the correct directory for it:
mount -o loop images/efiboot.img /mnt
vi /mnt/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.conf

Change this:
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.9
        kernel /images/pxeboot/vmlinuz
        initrd /images/pxeboot/initrd.img
title Install system with basic video driver
        kernel /images/pxeboot/vmlinuz nomodeset askmethod
        initrd /images/pxeboot/initrd.img

to this:
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.9
        kernel /images/pxeboot/vmlinuz inst.ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg
        initrd /images/pxeboot/initrd.img
title Install system with basic video driver
        kernel /images/pxeboot/vmlinuz nomodeset askmethod inst.ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg
        initrd /images/pxeboot/initrd.img

(or just add a new title/kernel/initrd line triplet with a custom title and the inst.ks option if you want the user to have the option of making a non-KS installation using the same media.)
Note that the above file uses GRUB configuration file syntax, not isolinux/SYSLINUX syntax.
Then:
cp /mnt/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.conf EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.conf
umount /mnt

Then proceed with your ISO image generation commands exactly as before.

I tried the method you gave, but it gets stuck at media test. When I manually select skip, it enters the graphical installation, which is inconsistent with the automated installation I expected. What went wrong?

If the installer needs some information that is not in your ks.cfg file, it will automatically display the appropriate part of the graphical installer so that you can fill in the missing information. If absolutely nothing in your ks.cfg seemed to work, there might be a problem in the boot option or reading the ks.conf file: use Ctrl-Alt-F2 in the installer to switch into a virtual console with root prompt, then check /proc/cmdline to see if the inst.ks option was registered, then verify you can read the file from the expected location on the mounted ISO.

Oops... it seems you read the Installation Guide of a RHEL release 7 or newer. RHEL 6.x used a slightly older syntax for the Kickstart boot option: it is not inst.ks= like in the modern releases, but just ks=. See "Starting Kickstart Installation" in RHEL 6.x Installation Guide

Thank you for your answer. You are right. I can log in normally after using ks= in BOOTX64.conf. But now there is a new problem. I set iP in ks
network --onboot yes --bootproto=static --device=9c:dc:71:b5:a4:b8 --ip=10.19.2.15 --netmask=255.255.254.0 --gateway=10.19.2.1 --noipv6
But after the installation is complete, the eth0 file still shows bootproto=dhcp, and ipv6 is also in yes state. I checked the official documentation and the parameters should be fine. I don't know why this happens.

The Installation Guide I linked says: "All static networking configuration information must be specified on one line". You seem to have two lines: one with network --hostname=temptest and another network ... line with all the other information. Add the --hostname=temptest option on the first line with all the other network parameters, and delete the second line.

Thanks, the problem is solved
